# Self localization inside machine of interest

Tags: localization, pose, point-cloud

I have a type of flight sensor interfaced with Arduino Uno via I2C. The sensor is VL53L0X i am getting the 1D measurement value of distance in mm which i can monitor using serial monitor in Arduino IDE. Looking for a software that can take real time values from COM port of PC when Arduino uno is attached via USB. After reading the values from serial port post process these values by taking mean values and draw point cloud. The algorithm needs to be efficient and reliable which can locate the sensor inside the object while the dimension of object is known.

Comment: Please add an image or more description to make this question answerable

Comment: is it understandable now ?